# How to retrieve java process & perform GC based on the java process memory?

Tags: java

I am interested to retrieve the java process from the task manager & perform GC based on the memory...

Can you provide any information to achieve it

Thanks & regards,
Krishna

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's pretty much what the JVM does on its own (and with a lot more detailed information that you have available outside of the process).

Comment: I am running a bigger application in Tomcat. presently i am manulay monitoring the JVM by using jconsole. My JVM commited 3.7GB, but the users are more, the system is structed & I need to restart the Tomcat.

Comment: "the system is structured"? What do you mean by that? It sounds like you need to tweak the memory configuration of your Tomcat.

Comment: I am running a bigger application in Tomcat. presently i am manulay monitoring the JVM by using jconsole. My JVM commited 3.7GB, but the users are more, the system is structed & I need to restart the Tomcat. I am thinking of how to perform GC by using java program when the heap memory reaches the 3GB above.. please provide suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description on how to get the current used memory:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/05/getting-jvm-heap-size-used-memory-total-memory-using-java-runtime.html

The Garbage Collector you can trigger by calling:

```
System.gc()
```

see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29 For a documentation

Comment: Note that for the latter point, you can merely *suggest* that the GC should be run.  A JVM/GC strategy is entirely at liberty to interpret this however - in particular, doing absolutely nothing is a legal implementation.

Comment: Yes that's true and also mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you wish to perform these operations on external process (`retrieve the java process from the task manager`).

I'd suggest you to check out JMX. This is the "normal" way to do it remotely. If JConsole does it you can implement it yourself too.

You have to use java.lang.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean